# What value will have class member that are pointers after deleteing the object from memory?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have such code:

```
class MyClass 
{
     typedef void (B::*F)(A*,C);

 private:
     A* member_pointerA;
     F  memberPointerB;

    void my_class_method()
    {
        if (some_condition)
             // call a callback Function
             callback1();

         if (member_pointerA && memberPointerB)
             //call another function and pass this
             callback2(this);
    }
};
```

Where `my_class_method` is a class method. `member_pointerA` and `memberPointerB` are pointer to `A` and function pointer to `void (B::*Something)(A*,C)` kind of thing. Somehow in the code such a situation occurs: `callback1()` appears to be a function that results to the call of the destructor of an object of type `MyClass` on which the `my_class_method` was called. But as the function execution is not finished second `if` condition should be checked for destructed object. Before `callback1()` call `member_pointerA` and `memberPointerB` were NULL, but after the call they somehow become not NULL, and programm crashes. When I exchange the places the `if`s then `if (member_pointerA && memberPointerB)` condition is not considered as both pointers are null. So what is the explanation that after deleting the object, member pointers change their value from NULL to some garbage?

Comment: you have a design problem here

Comment: Agree! I use a lib, and in that lib designers didn't consider that I can do such an action, that the object can be removed. But anyway, I think the pointers should become NULL even if they were not, but it is the opposite, they were, but they become not NULL, i.e. they obtained a value :)

Comment: A deleted object no longer exists, don't try to do anything with it.

Comment: After you burn a piece of paper, what words are written on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `callback1` deletes the object on which it is called, probably via `delete this;` somewhere down the call stack. If that is the case, you may not do anything with the object after the execution of `callback1`, meaning a call to any nonstatic member function and usage of any nonstatic member variables yields undefined behavior:

```
void my_class_method()
{
    if (some_condition)
         // call a callback Function
         callback1();              //maybe calls "delete this"

     if (member_pointerA && memberPointerB)  // use of member variables -> UB!!!
         //call another function and pass this
         callback2(this);                    // use of "this" -> UB!!!
}
```

Note: if `callback2` is not a method of `MyClass`, the call itself is not UB, but the function surely tries to access the object that is passed, and that would be UB since it is access to a deleted object.

The best course of action is obviously not having a callback that would delete the object it is called from. On rare occasions, self-deletion is the right thing to do, but it should be happening in a very obvious way and not behind the scenes via some callback.

If you have to delete the object in the course of `my_method`, the most obvious way to do so would be calling `delete this` in the method and not doing it in some callback. `callback1` then could return some value indicating wether the object should be deleted or not:

```
void my_class_method()
{
  if (some_condition)
  {
    bool doSelfDelete = callback1();  
    if (doSelfDelete) 
    {
      delete this;
      return;         
    }
  } 
}
```

Another possibility is to use smart pointers (a good choice anyways) and prolong the life of the object by accuiring a `shared_ptr` to `this`:

```
void my_class_method()
{
  auto self = shared_from_this(); //this is a standard library function, you need to derive from std::enable_shared_from_this<MyClass> to use it.
  if (some_condition)
  {
    callback1(); //won't call a explicit delete since we are working with smart pointers, but may erase some shared_ptr to this object
    // but since "self" is a shared_ptr too, it won't destroy this object
  } 
  if (member_pointerA && memberPointerB)  //ok 
  {
    callback2(self); //since we don't use raw pointers any more...
  }
} //now when self gets destroyed, "this" might get deleted as well.
```

What you can do if it *has* to be a self-deleting callback for some reason:

1. Let `callback1` return something that indicates if the object has been deleted (you cannot have it set a member variable because you cannot access that if it has been deleted):

   ```
   void my_class_method()
   {
       if (some_condition)
       {
         bool isDeleted = callback1();  //maybe calls "delete this"
         if (isDeleted) return;         //since isDeleted is not a member, you may use it
       } 
   }
   ```
2. If both conditions exclude each other, use `else if`:

   ```
   void my_class_method()
   {
       if (some_condition)
       {
         callback1();  //maybe calls "delete this"
       } 
       else if (member_pointerA && memberPointerB)
       {
         callback2(this); 
       }
   }
   ```

   While conceptually this may or may not be the same, it is a huge difference, because the second condition ony gets evaluated if the first has been false and therefore `callback1` and the self-deletion can not have occured.
3. If the order of the two callbacks does not matter, change it, so that `callback1` is the last thing that can get executed:

   ```
   void my_class_method()
   {
       if (member_pointerA && memberPointerB)
       {
         callback2(this); 
       }
       if (some_condition)
       {
         callback1();  //maybe calls "delete this"
       } 
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you very much for the details explanation and suggesting the solutions. I would like to open the braces and tell what is behind the code. This is a game engine, where in order to show something (image, button) you should `addChild` it. Also for these objects there is a reference counter to destruct the objects. If you `addChild` the counter increases, if you `removeChild` the counter decreases. Now in order to remove a button from the view in the callback of `button_pressed_event` I call `removeFromParent`. Which result the button to be destroyed. And hence the crash.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a pointer after object deletion is undefined. I often use a macro that invokes the `delete` operator and then assigns zero to the pointer.

Comment: Why a macro? If you must do such, a template would be safer.

Comment: So if I call destructor of my object, the member pointers of that object can obtain any value they wish?

Comment: @Narek Worse, if you call the destructor, the act of reading the members can have any behavior whatsoever (e.g. crashing the program), not just "they have some unspecified value".

Comment: @SebastianRedl yes I guess that is what is happening to me :D